# CRM 4.0 Preview View (preview.aspx) is cached at client

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-headers, dynamics-crm

[image: preview arrow in the orange square]

When doing updates to accounts in CRM 4.0, the preview does not update unless we clear the client cache. When requesting the preview (which happens when you click the little arrow shown in the screenshot) with URL shown below, the headers shown below are returned.

```
GET http://crmdev/DevOrg/_grid/preview.aspx?type=1&id={755E4F74-007D-E011-A3BC-005056B6001D} HTTP/1.1
```

As can be seen from the headers, there is no expiration date/time on the cache.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1006
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Persistent-Auth: false
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <token removed>
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2011 13:35:10 GMT
```

Setting the cache to expire using the method described in the following link has no effect. http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

Does anyone have a supported fix for Dynamics CRM 4.0 regarding the caching of the preview.aspx page? Almost all other examined pages in CRM returns 'Cache-Control: no-cache', so seemingly this file overrides the output header.

**ADDITIONAL INFO ADDED**

This behavior only affects IE9. Either IE9 is handling the caching unlike IE8 and before or IE9 is not allowing the corss tab/popup cache invalidation.

**Suggested hotfix (unsupported):** Replace preview.aspx with a custom aspx file that uses the original renamed file and has manual control over the cache header. Setting the cache-header to 'no-cache' solves this issue in IE9. We have opted out of this solution as it is unsupported, but it has been tested ok and requires no altering of aspx-content, only "rerouting".

Comment: Are you accessing this via the web interface or the outlook client?  also which roleup are you on?

Comment: I am using the web interface, with rollup 17.

Comment: I also tested that getting this changed to 'Cache-Control: no-cache' resolves this. I used fiddler's replace header functionality to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior only affects IE9. Either IE9 is handling the caching unlike IE8 and before or IE9 is not allowing the cross tab/popup cache invalidation.

*Suggested hotfix (unsupported):* Replace preview.aspx with a custom aspx file that uses the original renamed file and has manual control over the cache header. Setting the cache-header to 'no-cache' solves this issue in IE9. We have opted out of this solution as it is unsupported, but it has been tested ok and requires no altering of aspx-content, only "rerouting".